# Few questions regarding ubuntu ami id in AWS missing in Amazon EC2 AMI Locator for ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am fetching the latest available ami id for ubuntu 18.04 LTS available in AWS with the below script

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1

aws ec2 describe-images \
 --filters Name=name,Values=ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64* \
 --query 'Images[*].[ImageId,CreationDate]' --output text \
 | sort -k2 -r \
 | head -n1
```

I don't find the ami-id fetched from above script in https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/  why ?

Can I still use the ami-id fetched from the script ?
Though I can find the second latest ami id from the script available in https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/  (us-east-1,18.04 LTS)

Comment: If the cli command returns it, then it's on AWS and you can use it. Perhaps the cloud-images website isn't always up to date

Answer (score 0):

This is because public AMIs that are at least 2 years old are deprecated and have reduced visibility.

> Starting today, all public AMIs will have the deprecation time set to two years after their creation date. This means that public AMIs that are more than two years old will by default be deprecated. Once an AMI is deprecated, it will no longer appear in DescribeImages API calls for users that aren’t the owner of the AMI. Deprecating an AMI only reduces the visibility of the AMI in untargeted searches, but continues to be usable and available to you. Users of a deprecated AMI can continue to launch instances and describe the deprecated AMI using its ID.

Reference: [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/03/amazon-machine-images-public-visibility-two-years)